# How to make visual studio update its error message in a python file?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I wrote several programs in Visual Studio Code, in python.
I always have issue with it:
For instance, I tried to execute a program taking a file as a variable (so a .txt)
I made a mistake on the document name when I called the function  ,so ofc, I get an error ( I wrote test1.xt instead of test.txt), so I correct it. However, everytime I execute the program, I still have the test1.txt error, even though I corrected it into test.txt. What should I do ?!
Thanks in advance...

I tried to execute the program again, deleting the call of the function, and doing another call without any success...

Comment: **if you fix a "problem" in your code and the error continue - that means that isn't the cause of the error**. Also, you have to provide your stack trace or no one will be able to figure out what error you've encountered.

Comment: I wrote another program, which I called using the test.txt, and it worked ! The problem in the second program comes from the test1.txt that I corrected with the test.txt:

Comment: Here is the error : FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test 1.txt'

Comment: furthermore, when I delete the call of the function, I still get this error ! It makes no sense

Comment: this filename contains a space, show us the code of the program executing

Comment: then you are executing a different file then the one you edit

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am kind of dumb, but you have to save the file lol
My bad
EDIT: I come from pyzo, so I'm kinda new to VS Code.

Comment: then delete the question

Comment: Maybe it will help someone new to VS Code as well

Comment: what do you want ffs, I realised my mistake, I corrected it, if you don't have something usefull or nice to say stfu

Comment: I always wondered why in books and websites they always tell to save after each piece of code, now I know

Comment: my comments are always useful, not all comments are nice